SPFx Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') in web part using workbench
Each time I tried to launch my web part through the workbench I got this error, I don;t understand why.:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

PILE DES APPELS :
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_fr-fr_28f6472cc264e6dc475aa6d735e23162.js:196:11058
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.loadComponent (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_fr-fr_28f6472cc264e6dc475aa6d735e23162.js:196:11026)
    at https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_fr-fr_28f6472cc264e6dc475aa6d735e23162.js:196:13234
    at async Promise.all (index 0)`. 

When I delete the 2 imports
import TauxPourGc from './TauxPourGc';

import { ITfaTauxProps } from './../AssetsCommun/ITfaTauxProps';

my web part worked. But when I use these two imports and I create a custom function render I got this error.
The version of Node is v18.20.3 the build tool version is 3.18.1; this is for SharePoint online so I used 1.19.0 SPFx version.
Here is the code of my web part:
ProdTauxGcWebParts.ts
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  type IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import type { IReadonlyTheme } from '@microsoft/sp-component-base';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import styles from './ProdTauxGcWebPart.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'ProdTauxGcWebPartStrings';
import {SPFI } from "@pnp/sp";
import { getSP } from './pnpjsConfig';
//import "@pnp/sp/lists";
//import "@pnp/sp/items";
//import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import TauxPourGc from './TauxPourGc';
import { ITfaTauxProps } from './../AssetsCommun/ITfaTauxProps';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';


export interface IProdTauxGcWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  _tauxAvant: string;
  _tauxApres: string;
  _comparaison: string;
  _libelle: string;
  _tag: string;
}

export default class ProdTauxGcWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IProdTauxGcWebPartProps> {

  private _isDarkTheme: boolean = false;
  private _environmentMessage: string = '';
  public sp: SPFI;

  public renderold(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<ITfaTauxProps> = React.createElement(
      TauxPourGc,
      {
        tauxAvant: this.properties._tauxAvant,
        tauxApres: this.properties._tauxApres,
        comparaison: this.properties._comparaison,
        libelle: this.properties._libelle,
        tag: this.properties._tag
      }
    );
    console.log('render create taux apres' + this.properties._tauxApres);
    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }
  


  public render(): void {
    console.log('render');
  //  console.log(TauxPourGc.toString());
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    <section class="${styles.prodTauxGc} ${!!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams ? styles.teams : ''}">
      <div class="${styles.welcome}">
        <img alt="" src="${this._isDarkTheme ? require('./assets/welcome-dark.png') : require('./assets/welcome-light.png')}" class="${styles.welcomeImage}" />
        <h2>Well done, ${escape(this.context.pageContext.user.displayName)}!</h2>
        <div>${this._environmentMessage}</div>
        <div>Web part property value: <strong>${escape(this.properties.description)}</strong></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Welcome to SharePoint Framework!</h3>
        <p>
        The SharePoint Framework (SPFx) is a extensibility model for Microsoft Viva, Microsoft Teams and SharePoint. It's the easiest way to extend Microsoft 365 with automatic Single Sign On, automatic hosting and industry standard tooling.
        </p>
        <h4>Learn more about SPFx development:</h4>
          <ul class="${styles.links}">
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" target="_blank">SharePoint Framework Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-graph" target="_blank">Use Microsoft Graph in your solution</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-teams" target="_blank">Build for Microsoft Teams using SharePoint Framework</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-viva" target="_blank">Build for Microsoft Viva Connections using SharePoint Framework</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-store" target="_blank">Publish SharePoint Framework applications to the marketplace</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/spfx-yeoman-api" target="_blank">SharePoint Framework API reference</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://aka.ms/m365pnp" target="_blank">Microsoft 365 Developer Community</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </section>`;
  }

  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('onInit NEW GC ');
    this.sp = getSP(this.context);
    console.log('onInit NEW GC ' + getSP.toString());
    return this._getEnvironmentMessage().then(message => {
      this._environmentMessage = message;
    });

   
  }



  private _getEnvironmentMessage(): Promise<string> {
    if (!!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams) { // running in Teams, office.com or Outlook
      return this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.teamsJs.app.getContext()
        .then(context => {
          let environmentMessage: string = '';
          switch (context.app.host.name) {
            case 'Office': // running in Office
              environmentMessage = this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentOffice : strings.AppOfficeEnvironment;
              break;
            case 'Outlook': // running in Outlook
              environmentMessage = this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentOutlook : strings.AppOutlookEnvironment;
              break;
            case 'Teams': // running in Teams
            case 'TeamsModern':
              environmentMessage = this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentTeams : strings.AppTeamsTabEnvironment;
              break;
            default:
              environmentMessage = strings.UnknownEnvironment;
          }

          return environmentMessage;
        });
    }

    return Promise.resolve(this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentSharePoint : strings.AppSharePointEnvironment);
  }

  protected onThemeChanged(currentTheme: IReadonlyTheme | undefined): void {
    if (!currentTheme) {
      return;
    }

    this._isDarkTheme = !!currentTheme.isInverted;
    const {
      semanticColors
    } = currentTheme;

    if (semanticColors) {
      this.domElement.style.setProperty('--bodyText', semanticColors.bodyText || null);
      this.domElement.style.setProperty('--link', semanticColors.link || null);
      this.domElement.style.setProperty('--linkHovered', semanticColors.linkHovered || null);
    }

  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}

TauxPourGc.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './../../AssetsCommun/TauxWebPart.module.scss';
import type { ITfaTauxProps } from './../AssetsCommun/ITfaTauxProps';
import FlecheBlancheHaut from './../../AssetsCommun/FlecheBlancheHaut.png';
import FlecheBlancheBas from './../../AssetsCommun/FlecheBlancheBas.png';
import FlecheBlancheMilieu from './../../AssetsCommun/FlecheBlancheEqual.png';

export default class TauxPourGc extends React.Component<ITfaTauxProps, {}> {
  
  private getTag(): string {
    console.log('getTag : ' + this.props.tag);
    return this.props.tag;
  }

  private getTauxActuel(): string {
    console.log('getTauxActuel : ' + this.props.tauxApres);
    return this.props.tauxApres;
  }

  private getLibelle(): string {
    console.log('getLibelle : ' + this.props.libelle);
    return this.props.libelle;
  }

  private getTauxAvant(): string {
    console.log('getTauxAvant : ' + this.props.tauxAvant);
    return this.props.tauxAvant;
  }

  private getArrowStyle(): JSX.Element {
    console.log('getArrowStyle function: ');
    if (this.props.tauxAvant !== undefined) {
      console.log('getArrowStyle function inside: ');
      console.log('getArrowStyle tauxAvant: ' + this.props.tauxAvant);
      console.log('getArrowStyle tauxApres: ' + this.props.tauxApres);

      const _TauxavantBase: string = this.props.tauxAvant.toString();
      const _TauxapresBase: string = this.props.tauxApres.toString();

      console.log('getArrowStyle _TauxavantBaseCustom: ' + _TauxavantBase);
      console.log('getArrowStyle _TauxapresBaseCustom: ' + _TauxapresBase);
    
      const tauxAvantFormatted = _TauxavantBase.replace(',', '.');
      const tauxApresFormatted = _TauxapresBase.replace(',', '.');

      const _LibelleBase: string = this.props.libelle.toString();
      console.log('getArrowStyle _LibelleBaseCustom: ' + _LibelleBase);

      const _ComparaisonBase: string = this.props.comparaison.toString();
      console.log('getArrowStyle _ComparaisonBaseCustom: ' + _ComparaisonBase);

      const _Tauxavant = parseFloat(tauxAvantFormatted);
      const _Tauxapres = parseFloat(tauxApresFormatted);

      if (!isNaN(_Tauxavant) && !isNaN(_Tauxapres)) {
        if (_Tauxapres < _Tauxavant) {
          console.log('_Tauxapres < _Tauxavant');
          return <img src={FlecheBlancheHaut} alt="Fleche Haut" />;
        } else if (_Tauxapres > _Tauxavant) {
          console.log('__Tauxapres > _Tauxavant');
          return <img src={FlecheBlancheBas} alt="Fleche Bas" />;
        } else {
          console.log('__Tauxapres = _Tauxavant');
          return <img src={FlecheBlancheMilieu} alt="Fleche Milieu" />;
        }
      }
      return <img src={FlecheBlancheMilieu} alt="Fleche Milieu" />;
    }
    return <div>Erreur</div>;
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<ITfaTauxProps> {
    console.log('render inside ');  
    const arrowStyle: JSX.Element = this.getArrowStyle();

    return (
      <div className={styles.preventionDisplay}> 
        <div className={styles.rectangle}> 
          <div className={styles.texteHautTitre}>
            <span>Génie Civil France</span>
          </div> 
          <div className={styles.texteHautTag}>
            <span>{this.getTag()}</span>
          </div> 
          <div className={styles.texteHautLib}>
            <span>{this.getLibelle()}</span>
          </div> 
          &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <div className={styles.row}> 
            <div className={styles.row}> 
              <div className={styles.arrowCustom}> 
                {arrowStyle && (
                  <span>
                    {arrowStyle}
                  </span>
                )}
              </div> 
              <div className={styles.avant}> 
                <span>{this.getTauxActuel()}</span>
              </div> 
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
              <div className={styles.separator}/> 
            </div> 
            <div className={styles.column}> 
              <div className={styles.pcustom}>
                &nbsp;
              </div> 
              <div className={styles.pcustom}>
                {this.getTauxAvant()}
              </div> 
              <div className={styles.pcustom}>La période</div> 
              <div className={styles.pcustom}>précédente</div> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
    );
  }
}

pnpjsConfig.ts
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
// import pnp and pnp logging system
import { spfi, SPFI, SPFx } from "@pnp/sp";
import { LogLevel, PnPLogging } from "@pnp/logging";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
import "@pnp/sp/batching";

// eslint-disable-next-line no-var
var _sp: SPFI ;

export const getSP = (context?: WebPartContext): SPFI => {
    console.log('getSP getSP');
  if (!!context) { // eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
    //You must add the @pnp/logging package to include the PnPLogging behavior it is no longer a peer dependency
    // The LogLevel set's at what level a message will be written to the console
    _sp = spfi().using(SPFx(context)).using(PnPLogging(LogLevel.Warning));
  }
  return _sp;
};

ITfaTauxProps.ts
export interface ITfaTauxProps {
    tauxAvant: string;
    tauxApres: string;
    comparaison: string;
    libelle: string;
    tag: string;
  }
  


I would recommend that you check version compatibility among all the SPFx components used in your project. I've the same error when incompatible components are imported into the project
